# Creating Gestures in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi i am following this tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html
i want to create an application in which user can add his gesture inmy application and then use it for authentication.i  know using this code i can check whether gesture entered by him is correct or not.

package de.vogella.android.gestures;

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class GestureTest extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureLibrary gestureLib;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!gestureLib.load()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ok but please help me that how to add in gesture in R.raw.animate file.please suggest any way or link for adding a gesture in android app .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extracted from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) :

> Android 1.6 and higher SDK platforms include a new application
>   pre-installed on the emulator, **called Gestures Builder. You can use
>   this application to create a set of pre-defined gestures for your own
>   application**...

...

> As you can see, a gesture is always associated with a name. That name
>   is very important because it identifies each gesture within your
>   application. The names do not have to be unique. Actually it can be
>   very useful to have several gestures with the same name to increase
>   the precision of the recognition. **Every time you add or edit a gesture
>   in the Gestures Builder, a file is generated on the emulator's SD
>   card, /sdcard/gestures. This file contains the description of all the
>   gestures, and you will need to package it inside your application
>   inside the resources directory, in /res/raw**.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/source/checkout) you have the source code of Gesture Builder

Gesture builder is installed in the emulator , but you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/downloads/detail?name=com.android.gesture.builder.apk)

And gesture source code examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/downloads/detail?name=GesturesDemos.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges)

Comment: i need the source code of Gesture Builder can you please provide a link for the source code of gesture builder and thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may need to call gestureLib.load() before using it

Comment: what are the reason that this becomes false, because that happens to me. Still trying to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Source code of gesture builder:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/apps/GestureBuilder/