# Android - Create gestures in my application

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition

I am creating an android application, In which I am implementing the "new gesture creation" and "gesture detection". I have searched in the internet.

I found this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778361/1485254

They mentioned,

> "Android 1.6 and higher SDK platforms include a new application
>   pre-installed on the emulator, called Gestures Builder. You can use
>   this application to create a set of pre-defined gestures for your own
>   application..."

But I should create these gestures from my application. Is it possible to do it from my application(Gesture creation). Can anyone give me a suggestion regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports the **Gesture API since version 1.6.** The API can be located in the package android.gesture, and lets you store, load, draw and recognize gestures. The below tutorial will show you a proof-of-concept application how you can make use of Gesture API.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/source/checkout) you have the source code of Gesture Builder

Gesture builder is installed in the emulator , but you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/downloads/detail?name=com.android.gesture.builder.apk)

And gesture source code examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/downloads/detail?name=GesturesDemos.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges)

Check out the [Create Gesture Programmatically in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to Create Gesture from my application not from other applications(like Gesture Builder). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. If you have checked the links of my answer you will come to know how to create gesture in your own application.